# Spring boot cache warm up

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cache

I need some basic understanding of spring cache function. I want to build a cache warmer and resyncer as scheduled bean, in order to renew the cache on demand, when changes happen.

Let say, I have an `AccountClient` with a `getAccount(String id)`, which fetches an `Account` from a very slow API. So basically I can do

```
@Cachable(cacheNames = "account", key = "#id", sync = true)
public Account getAccount(String id) {
   //...
}
```

and everything works fine. Now I want to warm up the cache, and furthermore, I got a `getNewOrChangedAccounts()`, which retrieves IDs of changed accounts from my slow datastore.

so here is my approach:

```
public class AccountCacheManager {

    //...

    @Scheduled(initialDelay = 3000L, fixedRate = 10000L)
    public void sync() {
        List<Account> modifiedAccounts = accountClient.getNewOrChangedAccounts();

        modifiedAccounts.getAccounts().parallelStream()
                .forEach(account -> {
                   //delete old entry
                   evictAccount(account.getId());
                   //store new entry
                   putAccount(account.getId());

               });


        log.info("finished resync");
    }

    @CacheEvict(cacheNames = "account", key = "#id")
    public void evictAccount(String id) {
        log.debug("evicting account {}", id);
    }

    @CachePut(cacheNames = "account", key = "#id")
    public void putAccount(String id) {
        log.debug("storing account {}", id);
        accountService.getAccount(id);
    }
}
```

So I can proof, this process gets started and does something. However, when I hit my API, I see the first hit going to the slow backend, even if my sync goes over all entries from the backend.

I feel I misunderstood some details of spring caching API, so how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/CachePut.html) for `@CachePut`:

> In contrast to the @Cacheable annotation, this annotation does not
>   cause the advised method to be skipped. Rather, it always causes the
>   method to be invoked and its result to be stored in the associated
>   cache.

So your method annotated with `@CachePut` should return the data to cache:

```
    @CachePut(cacheNames = "account", key = "#id")
    public Account putAccount(String id) {
        log.debug("storing account {}", id);
        return accountService.getAccount(id);
    }
```

See also this question: [Spring Cacheable vs CachePut?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28516398/spring-cacheable-vs-cacheput)

Comment: after few days, it still doesn't work for some reason...is caching working separated for requests?

Comment: it looks like working when using `CacheManager` directly, simply annotating with @CachePut and return is not enough

Comment: @DavidSteiman I think it's because annotated method (with @ Cache*, @ Transactionnal, etc.) must be called from outside the class (which is not the case in your AccountCacheManager) see https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/6.0.3/reference/html/integration.html#cache-annotation-enable

Answer (score 1):

Under the hood, when `@Cacheable` or `@CachePut` annotation is declared on a class, Spring  creates a proxy class that wrap around the bean instance create from that class.

This abstract caching layer will **only be usable** by any method invocation from **outside** of that class.

The easy solution to the problem above is to separate the cron method into a different class and call the cached method through injected bean instead.

```java
@Component
public class AccountCacheManager {

    //...

    @CachePut(cacheNames = "account", key = "#id")
    public Account putAccount(String id) {
        log.debug("storing account {}", id);
        return accountService.getAccount(id);
    }
}

@Component
public class CacheWarmupManager {

    // bean injected here is actually a proxy that wrapped AccountCacheManager with cache implementation
    @Autowired private AccountCacheManager accountManager;

    @Scheduled(initialDelay = 3000L, fixedRate = 10000L)
    public void sync() {
        List<Account> modifiedAccounts = accountClient.getNewOrChangedAccounts();

        modifiedAccounts.getAccounts().parallelStream()
                .forEach(account -> {
                   // force update Cache with new Entry
                   accountManager.putAccount(account.getId());
               });


        log.info("finished resync");
    }
}
```

**Note:**
The reason why your cache warm up cron method didn't work was because the method is on **same class** of the cached method. So, when ever the cron triggered, it make a direct call to the `putAccount` and `evictAccount` method **without passing through the proxy class** that provided the cache.