# Spring cache on create new item

Tags: java, spring, caching

I'm using item ID to identify caching data like this:

```
@CachePut(value = "users", key = "#p0.id")
@RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public User updateUser(@RequestBody User user);
```

Function create new Item return item ID after created. How can I save item into cache after create new Item?

```
@Cacheable(value = "users", key = "???")
@RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public User createUser(@RequestBody User user);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use @CachePut

```
@CachePut(value = "users", key = "#result.id"")
@RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public User createUser(@RequestBody User user);
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to create service class and put all those methods in it.
Also on store method (in your case createUser method) you should put annotation 
`@CachePut(value = "user", key = "#user.id")`.

Something like this:

```
@CachePut(value = "user", key = "#user.id")
public User createUser(User user) { 
   // store user in db...
}
```

Try code above.

Answer (score 1):

Use @CachePut on creating new items.

You may refer this for differences between @CachePut and @Cacheable:
[Spring Cacheable vs CachePut?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28516398/spring-cacheable-vs-cacheput)