# Getting object from Hazlcast cache is immutable

Tags: java, caching, hazelcast

I'm currently having a problem(?) with Hazelcast cache. I have a method that is annotated with Cacheable. It returns an object with user info (id,username and securityId (list of strings))

For my business case I need to get user object and update securityIds, for the first run (when object is not in cache) it works fine. For the second time I get UnsupporteOperationException when add() method is invoked on list (on object which is now getting from cache).

Is it because object from cache is transformed to immutable? Or it's configuration issue?

Answer (score 0):

See [Spring Cacheable vs CachePut?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28516398/spring-cacheable-vs-cacheput)

Or for more detail https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.15.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html#cache-annotations